# How to prove these two statements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A,B,C,D$ be real matrices (not necessarily square) such that
$$A^T=BCD$$$$B^T=CDA$$$$C^T=DAB$$$$D^T=ABC.$$
For the matrix $S=ABCD$, prove that

$$S^3=S$$ and $$S^2=S^4.$$

My little brother got this in a test yesterday. I have read the homework policy here, but I seriously have no idea how to get on with this one.

Comment: $$S^3=(ABC)(DAB)(CDA)(BCD)=D^TC^TB^TA^T=(ABCD)^T=S^T.$$

Comment: @ofir it is still to show that $S=S^T$

Comment: @Peter $SS^T=((ABC)(D))(D^TC^TB^TA^T)=D^TC^TB^TA^TD^TC^TB^TA^T=(S^T)^2\Rightarrow S=S^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start by showing that $S=S^T$:
\begin{align}S&=ABCD=A(BCD)=AA^T\\
S^T&=(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T\\
\therefore S&=S^T\end{align}

Now, we give an expression for $S^3$:
\begin{align}S^3&=SSS\\
&=(ABCD)(ABCD)(ABCD)\\
&=(ABC)(DAB)(CDA)(BCD)=D^TC^TB^TA^T\\
&=(ABCD)^T\\
&=S^T\\
&=S\end{align}

Multiplying each side by $S$ yields the expected result, i.e.:
$$S^4=S^2$$

Comment: That was a neat explanation. Thankyou.

Comment: Why $SS^T=S^2$ implies $S=S^T$? Did you use invertibility here?